# How to shorten the asserts?

Tags: karate

How we can shorten this:

```
And match response !contains { foo: '#notnull' }
And match responseHeaders !contains { foo: '#notnull' }
```

Sorry if we didn't find a response in the official tuto

Comment: Before I react to this, maybe I'm not understanding properly. Can you please give me an example of what you are expecting ?

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Thomas, we would like to do smth like: And match response, responseHeaders !contains {foo: '#notnull'} to 'assert' that neither response, nor responseHeaders contains an element 'foo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your comment and if you ask my honest opinion, you are expecting too much from a JSON assertion framework. Really ?  This is what you are most worried about ?

So the short answer is Karate does not support what you are expecting, directly.

That said - you can write a custom JavaScript (or Java) function in Karate to get the values of the `response` and the `responseHeaders` and then do whatever you want. I leave that as an exercise to you to figure out.